# Use of would in english

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

What is the meaning of below sentnece using would?

But the baby's disappearance would fox police for days.

for contex please read.

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/delhi/Delhi-teen-kills-2-year-old-to-avenge-insult/articleshow/47714093.cms

Comment: It's a normal *would* as the past of *will*.

Comment: @ Demkerng I don't thik so

Comment: You can (and should) add what you think in your question. I could've been wrong because I didn't read the whole story (it's too long to read in a few seconds), but I assumed that the story was told in the past tense (aka narrative past), and the tenses used in the story were (or should be, if my assumption is correct) shifted to the past accordingly.

Comment: read... *very brutal*. **And** @DamkerngT. is right! :)

Comment: @Demkerng. You were right, prima facie sentence mean the same as you said. But in context is means it is repetation of police foxing.

Comment: I think @user4084 might be confused about the fact that the events in the story took place in the past, but the sentence uses "would" as if to imply that the baby has not disappeared yet. In the context of a story or events that took place in the past, we can use "would" to mean that "it will happen later in the story." In other words, the "present" is what's currently happening in the story, not the actual present in real time.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *would* is often used to express past routine or typical behaviour that was frequently repeated. In this case, the *baby's disappearance* kept on *foxing* the police *for days*.

Here are a few other examples, they also express repetitive behaviour in the past:

> - Grandfather would sit on the porch and smoke his cigarette.
> - I would arrive at school and look for my friends.
> - My cat would chase the ball until he was tired.

You can learn more about it [here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/past1c.html).